# Call a function of a Web User Control from the parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, web-user-controls, webusercontrol

I'm creating a comments web user control. I want to use this comments control on distinct pages like: articles, attractions and categories.

So, on the articles page I declare the Web User Control

```
 <uc1:Comments ID="Comments1" runat="server"  />
```

On the control, there is a function call loadComments

```
public void LoadComents(int ID,string type)
{
        //Load the comments into an asp.net repeater that resides on the control 
}
```

which I want to call once I have validated that the article exists.
So on the article page I want do something like

```
Comments1.LoadComents(101,"article");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this from inside of your Page class:

```
Comments commentsControl = this.FindControl("Comments1");
commentsControl.LoadComents(1, "someType");
```

Or if the control exists on the page in Designer, you should be able to do something as simple as:

```
this.Comments1.LoadComents(1, "someType");
```

Comment: Thanks Justin,

I was doing that and some how it dosn't work, but know it's working

Answer (score 0):

On the UserControl Code-Behind I have the following code:

```
    public void SetPageTitle(string strTitle)
    {
        lPageTitle.Text = strTitle;
    }
```

On the Page Code-Behind that contains/included the UserControl

```
   {
       PageTitle.SetPageTitle(cat.categoryName);
   }
```

This is working ...